# Mapping GPS points with Augmented Reality

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, augmented-reality

I'm trying to make a Windows Phone app that shows GPS points on the camera using Augmented Reality. I've been looking for tutorials online but I can't find any anywhere that explain how to do it. I was wondering if anybody knew of any good tutorials that explain combining AR with GPS, or if anybody could give me any tips on where to begin (I don't expect a detailed explanation or anything). Even a tutorial on how to do it with Android would be a start.

Comment: -1 for not choosing an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the "Geo Augmented Reality Toolkit" on Codeplex. It abstracts nearly all complex tasks for you, you just have to add some points with their coordinates and what to display and everything else works with a couple lines of code.

http://gart.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Knowing where the device is currently located using (which is quite easy, at least on Android) and the relative positioning of closest (this is up to implementation) GPS marks (these should be loaded from somewhere obviously).

Magnetometer should give you where you're facing the device, which gives you the bearing (e.g. 180º = bearing south). This way you can calculate a vision cone of which markers you want to show.

You only need to draw stuff over the camera image ;)

Comment: Thanks! It's sort of the drawing stuff that's confusing me. How do you tell the device where on the camera the point should be drawn? Obviously it knows where the point is in the real world but how would you translate the real world to the screen? I can't wrap my head around it >.>

Comment: Accelerometer should give you where you're facing the device, which gives you the bearing. This way you can calculate a vision cone of which markers you want to show.

Comment: Hmm... ok, I'll try to apply that to what code samples i have. Thanks for the help =)

Comment: Accelerometers give you orientation with respect to the gravity vector: it can give you every other element of your orientation _except_ your bearing. Global bearing is determined with a magnetometer (relative bearing with a gyroscope). The accelerometer is involved in projecting the magnetic vector to a plane, but it doesn't give the bearing.

Answer (score 1):

I've described one approach to go from knowing your GPS and orientation, and the GPS of some points of interest to knowing where on screen those points should be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898301/312007